# Error on deploying OpenStack infrastructure

Tags: deployment, openstack

I'm going to deploy Openstack as an infrastructure on 3 servers as described below.
3 Hp DL380 G7 servers with 2TB HDD that separated in 2 logical volume , the Ubuntu 22.04 is installed on a 200Gb logical volume and fully updated, also each servers has at least 128gb RAM.
the second logical volume has been reserved for infrastructure
the problem :

i have follow this instruction to deploy the OpenStack
[Multi-node mode cluster](https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#single-multi-large-cluster)

after 2 steps successfully doing the script , at the 3rd step it prompts an error and ends with no success . I will attached the screenshot too at the end.

the error indicates

> Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready.
>
> Error: Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abnVZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.